# Is there a way to get the date and time a user last changed their password in Google Workspace

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

We are moving away from AD and going to Google Work space as our LDAP service. One of my tasks are to reproduce some tools that we have on AD to Google Workspace. One of those tools is the ability to warn a user 14 days before a password is about to expire then 7 days before and send us (IT admins) a warning 4 days before to catch it before they get locked out. So I have created this tool in PowerShell on windows and LDAP and I am trying to use Google App Scripts to do this. I have learned that the Directory API does not expose this metadata on the user (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) and I have to use the Admin Report API and search the logs for an eventName called CHANGE_PASSWORD and then build an array of user email address and the last time they changed their password.

I have got this successfully working to show me a HTML output of email address and how many days left till their password expires in a table that is generated on demand when you load the web app, but I noticed we have 120 users in our Org and only 78 users show up on the list. So then I realized that the reports section of Google Admin reports only stores 6 months worth of logs. To me the reports section is not a reliable source to determine when the user last changed their password. Does anyone have any other ideas as to how I can accurately get the date a Google Workspace user last changed their password? Here is what I currently have if anyone wants to build on this:

Please note you must add the Admin SDK API service to your script and the user running the script my have the role for reports on your domain. This is not polished code but just a proof of concept so be gentle with your replies and comments about my sloppy code

code.gs

```
const maxPasswordAge = 90;

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getListOfUsers() {
 const userKey = 'all';
  const applicationName = 'admin';
  const optionalArgs = {
    eventName: 'CHANGE_PASSWORD'
  };

  const logs = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
  const activities = logs.items;
  
  if (activities && activities.length > 0) {
    var passwordLastChanged = new Object();
    for (i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
      const activity = activities[i];
      const key = activity.events[0].parameters[0]['value'];
      const value = activity.id.time;

      // If the key does not exist then add it
      if (!passwordLastChanged.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        passwordLastChanged[key] = value;
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No results found.');
  }

  // You will now have an object with emailaddress:Date last Changed

  const todaysDate = new Date();
  
  // Change the date to a number of days till it expires from today's date
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(passwordLastChanged)) {
    const dateLastChange = new Date(value);
    const milliBetweenDate = todaysDate - dateLastChange;
    const diffInDays = milliBetweenDate / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    passwordLastChanged[key] = (maxPasswordAge - diffInDays).toFixed(1);

  }

  // Change the object to a sorted array based on the days left till password expires
  const entries = Object.entries(passwordLastChanged);
  const sorted = entries.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);

  return sorted;

}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: gray;}
.tg {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.td {border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px; overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal; color: floralwhite;}
.col1, .col2, .col3  {text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.col4, .col5 {text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table id="myTable" class="tg">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="col3">Email</td>
    <td class="col5">Days Left</td>    
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  
  // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addUsersToTable).getListOfUsers();
  });

  function addUsersToTable(userArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
      $('#myTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td class="col3">' + userArray[i][0] + '</td><td class="col5">' + userArray[i][1] + '</td></tr>');
    }
  }

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone on another channel suggested that i get a list of all users in my org and then assume if the user is not in the password array then their password must be at minimum older then 6 months. Its a great work around but its a really mickey mouse solution and seems sloppy. There has to be a better way to get the actual date a password was last changed the n using the reports.

Answer (score 0):

So yes , 6 months is the maximum they keep the logs. If you are on the Enterprise SKU (which Is unlikely with 120 users) you can export logs to Bigquery indefinably and Query that. https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365?hl=en If you have something else that is able to  ingest the logs you can do that too.

However , I did something for the suspension date as that date is not set in a user field either.

You are going to need 2 processes.

Create a custom schema attribute for your password date option.
Have a process that routinely scrapes the audit logs. Say everyday you look for password changes in the past 24 hours. You then set the value on the custom schema attribute accordingly.

You second process will monitor that custom schema attribute and do your alerting to users.

To start I had to make an assumption. All users that didn't meet existing criteria would have a fixed date set. Moving forward this new process would ensure everything is inline.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I 100% agree that this is currently the only solution so I am going to mark this as solved. I need to generate my password reports on demand as we use a Google Chat Bot to present us with the report so I am just doing the updating on demand more then a hourly or daily script.